# Parse Input to child component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

I'm tying to make a dynamic navbar with Angular materials.

The idea is to create a "template" of a navbar that could be re-used in future projects, however I'm facing a difficulty while trying to order my navbar components.

Let's say we have 4 components:

- 1 parent component (app-nav-bar)
- 3 child components (app-nav-bar-logo-image, app-nav-bar-logo-text, app-nav-bar-links)

What I would like to do is whenever I'm calling a parent component with specific agument only these components to appear, on the other hand I would like to be able to order those child components as I like.
[A simple representaion of an idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCbB0.png)

For some reason the placeElementsInOrder() function sorts the array with default values (100, 101, 102) instead of the ones that I'm passing in the app.component.html.

How can I first pass the arguments to a component and after they are passed then to sort them based on their order?

app.component.html

```
<app-nav-bar
  [logoIcon]="logo"
  [logoText]="logoText"
  [navigationOptions]="navigationOptions">
</app-nav-bar>
```

app.component.ts

```
  logo = {    
    src: '../assets/images/logo.svg',
    path: './home',
    alternativeText: 'Logo',
    order: 3
  };

  logoText = {    
    path: './home',
    text: 'LOGO',
    order: 2
  };

  menuItems = [
    { label: 'HOME', path: '#' },
    { label: 'ABOUT', path: '#' },
    { label: 'PROJECTS', path: '#' },
    { label: 'CONTACT', path: '#' }
  ];

  navigationOptions = {
    navigationMenuItems: this.menuItems,
    order: 1
  };
```

nav-bar.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
        <ng-container class="navbar__items" *ngFor="let itemToAdd of listOfOrder">
            ...
        </ng-container>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

nav-bar.component.ts

```
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() logoIcon: logoIconModel = {
    src: '',
    path: '',
    alternativeText: '',
    order: 100
  };

  @Input() logoText: logoTextModel = {   
    path: '',
    text: '',
    order: 101
  }

  @Input() navigationOptions: navigationMenuLinksModel = {   
    navigationMenuItems: [{
        label: '', path: ''
      } as navigationMenuItemModel
    ], 
    order: 102
  }

  constructor(){}

  listOfOrder = placeElementsInOrder(this.logoIcon, this.logoText, this.navigationOptions);
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}

function placeElementsInOrder(logoIcon: logoIconModel, logoText: logoTextModel, navigationOptions: navigationMenuLinksModel): Array<any> {
  const listOfItems: any[] = [
    { order: logoIcon.order, type: 'logoIcon' },
    { order: logoText.order, type: 'logoText' },
    { order: navigationOptions.order, type: 'navMenuLinks' }
  ];
  return listOfItems.sort( (a,b) => a.order - b.order );
}
```

nav-bar.models.ts

```
export interface logoIconModel {
    src: string
    path: string
    alternativeText: string
    order: number
}

export interface logoTextModel {
    path: string
    text: string
    order: number
}

export interface navigationMenuItemModel {
    label: string
    path: string
}

export interface navigationMenuLinksModel {
    navigationMenuItems: navigationMenuItemModel[]
    order: number
}
```

nav-bar-logo-image.component.html

```
<a *ngIf="logoIcon" [routerLink]="logoIcon.path">
    <img [src]="logoIcon.src" [alt]="logoIcon.alternativeText">
</a>
```

nav-bar-logo-text.component.html

```
<a *ngIf="logoText" [routerLink]="logoText.path">
    {{logoText.text}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `placeElementsInOrder` function on `ngOnChanges`.

`ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook runs when `Input` value changes. Since you are already running the `placeElementsInOrder` function when component loads it disregards the new values (coming from `Input`) and use the default values you have in the component.

```
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

export class NavBarComponent implements OnChanges
{
    public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void
    {
        this.listOfOrder = this.placeElementsInOrder(this.logoIcon, this.logoText, this.navigationOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. So any canges that are done during component loading can be captured by ngOnChanges.

Comment: not every change, Only when `Input` (also known as data-bound properties) value changes, those are captured by `ngOnChanges`